# Understanding $ in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I have some difficulty understanding the following code (executed in an ErrorT monad layered on top of IO):

```
closePort [Port port] = liftIO $ hClose port >> (return $ Bool True)
```

`>>` has higher precendence than `$`. So is `Bool True` first wrapped in IO and than lifted with `liftIO` or is `hClose` lifted first? In other words are `>>` and `return` executed in the IO monad or in ErrorT monad?

Answer (score 14):

You don't really have to worry about precedence in this case, because

```
liftIO (hClose port >> return (Bool True))
```

and

```
liftIO (hClose port) >> return (Bool True)
```

must be equivalent due to the monad transformer laws, which say that

1. Lifting `return` does nothing.

   ```
   lift . return = return
   ```
2. Lifting a sequence of two actions is the same as lifting them separately.

   ```
   lift (m >>= f) = lift m >>= (lift . f)
   ```

`liftIO` should also follow these laws, so we can see that

```
liftIO (hClose port >> return (Bool True))
= -- definition of >>
liftIO (hClose port >>= \_ -> return (Bool True))
= -- second monad transformer law
liftIO (hClose port) >>= \_ -> liftIO (return (Bool True))
= -- first monad transformer law
liftIO (hClose port) >>= \_ -> return (Bool True)
= -- definition of >>
liftIO (hClose port) >> return (Bool True)
```

Comment: This is true and important to know, but I don't really think it answers the question, which I read to be about lexical syntax.  You assert that `liftIO $ hClose port >> return (Bool True) === liftIO (hClose port >> return (Bool True))`, but don't say why, which seems to be the whole point of the question.

Comment: @JohnL He says precisely why the are the same. But you have a point - he doesn't answer the literal question about operator precedence.

Comment: @delnan: if you don't know how to parse a language, how can you tell that two expressions are equivalent?

Answer (score 7):

The given code is equivalent to

```
closePort [Port port] = liftIO ( hClose port >> (return ( Bool True) ) )
```

so the entire `(hClose port) >> (return (Bool True))` is the argument to `liftIO`. So the `(>>)` and `return` are the ones of `IO`, and then the entire `IO`-computation is lifted with `liftIO`.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm assuming `Bool` here is a data constructor of a type you've defined.)

```
liftIO $ hClose port >> (return $ Bool True)
```

is the same as

```
liftIO (hClose port >> (return (Bool True)))
```

So the `return` and the `>>` are both the `IO` versions, and the result of the `>>` is lifted into the outer monad.

Answer (score 1):

Operators with higher precedence bind more tightly than operators with low precedence.

To figure out the ordering when multiple operators are in an expression, start with the highest-precedence operator and put parentheses around the expressions on either side, then continue this down through operator precedence.  For operators of the same level, you determine the order based on their defined associativity.  It's illegal to mix operators of the same precedence level but different associative behaviors, as the grouping is then ambiguous.  The procedure is probably familiar from working with numerical operators:

```
2 + 3 * 5 - 1 + 2
-- * is infixl 7
2 + (3 * 5) - 1 + 2
-- + and - are infixl 6, so apply parens starting at the left
(2 + (3 * 5)  - 1) + 2
```

((2 + (3 * 5)) - 1) + 2

Since `>>` has a higher precedence than `$`, applying the same treatment to

```
liftIO $ hClose port >> (return $ Bool True)
```

gives you

```
liftIO $ (hClose port >> (return $ Bool True))
```

So first the `hClose` and `return $ Bool True` are combined into an expression with type `IO (Bool')`, which is then lifted with `liftIO`.  (Where `Bool'` is whatever type `Bool True` has).

The [Haskell Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/) provides a thorough treatment of syntax, particularly chapters 2, 3, and 9.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to look at the implementation of `$`:

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
f $ x = f x
```

This means, that `x` will be evaluated if required by `f`. Until then, we have that

```
f $ expression for x = f (expression for x)
```

In your case, we have that

```
x = hClose port >> (return ( Bool True) )
f = liftIO
```

which would mean that

```
f $ expression for x = f (expression for x)
                     = liftIO (expression for x)
                     = liftIO (hClose port >> (return ( Bool True) ))
```

I hope that clarifies it.

Comment: “This means, that it must evaluate `x` before it can apply `f`.” Um, no. Semantically `$` is normal function application: `f` must be evaluated before we apply `f` to `x`, but `x` will only be evaluated if `f` demands it. (The only difference between `$` and normal function application is syntactic.) Perhaps you are confusing `$` with [`$!`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v:-36--33-)?

Comment: Try with `f = const 42` and `x = undefined`, and you will see that `x` does not have to be evaluated.

Comment: Fixed it, should be true now then.

Comment: This answer (seemingly about lazy evaluation??) also has nothing to do with the question, which was about the binding precedence of function application vs. $ vs. >> and how  Haskell proceeds with reducing the given form.

Comment: I'm just trying to explain where the parentheses from other peoples answers are coming from, ie. why `f $ x` is the same as writing `f(x)`. I do not believe that the others explained this very well. It is this fact that changes the precedences, as far as I'm aware. The lazyness also relies on this, even though this was more of a side notion.